# Symfony2 secure whole controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

Im having different user-actions within a controller. I want to secure them so anonymous users cant access this actions. (they not rely to a special prefix-path)

According to:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-a-controller

I have to secure every action seperate. This is not very handy and produces duplicate code.

Is there a possibility to throw accessdenied exception for ALL actions of a controller?

Answer (score 1):

You need to secure it in security.yml

Right where the `access_control` section is:

This is how one of my projects look like.

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/oauth, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Now in the controller, in this case for the first line, I just add the following annotation at the top of the class:

```
/**
 * Class OAuthController
 * @package MyNamespace\MyBundle\Controller
 * @Route("/oauth")
 */
class OAuthController extends Controller {
}
```

And the whole controller is secured.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. If you really have a lot of actions you could write your own annotation that would run everytime an action is performed.

You should really think about using access control in your security.yml. Why don't you add the specific pattern for every action there? If there is no specific prefix you can still restrict full urls there.

Comment: It is possible. Look at @AlanChavez's answer.

Comment: Nope. Alan's answer also relies on acces_control. Take a closer look. I said that it's not possible without blocking a pattern. And that still holds.

Comment: You're right. Too bad it won't let me change the downvote. @coil's answer looks promising though.

Comment: @Fred Is it a bad thing to block a pattern? That's my usual approach when it comes to securing controller, shouldn't that be the way to do it?

Comment: @AlanChavez Yes you're right too but I believe OP doesn't want to block a pattern. "They not rely to a special prefix-path".

Comment: @Tek Gotcha. Then OP's question doesn't make sense. You can't block an entire controller in a single annotation without blocking a pattern. Regardless of where you put that pattern (security.yml or inside the controller) at the end of the day you have to block a pattern.

Comment: That's exactly what I said ;)